# Convert java string to string compatible with a regex in replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, replace, replaceall

Is there a library or any easy way to convert a string and make sure its compatible as a regex to look for and replace in another string. So if the string is "$money" it would get converted to "\$money". I tried using StringEscapeUtil.escape but it doesn't work with characters such as $.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Pattern.quote("$money")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 8):

Prepend the `\\Q` in front of the string, and `\\E` at the end:

```
"\\Q$money\\E"
```

This tells the regex engine that the string between `\Q` and `\E` must be interpreted verbatim, ignoring any metacharacters that it may contain.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently this is what Pattern.quote() does.

Comment: But what if the String contains `\\E` in it ?